# Matlab- out of memory : image processing

Tags: image, matlab, memory, out-of-memory

I need to process 218 images in matlab (4056x6288 arrays, 16bits), processing involves cropping certain regions and calculating some variables. I get the out of memory error. Any ideas on how to prevent this error?

Comment: work on 1 image at a time and only store the variables and remove old images between runs? you can also crop outside of matlab using python, ffmpeg or similar and then only load the smaller images into matlab.

Answer (score 0):

4056x6288*218*16 bit is 11 GB of data. Looks like this is simply too much data at the same time. Avoid storing all images in ram at the same time.